# Deploy Multiple Services inside same Service fabric application type

Tags: appfabric, azure-service-fabric

Is it possible to Create multiple services under a single Application type name.

I have two service fabric application packages, both have the same application type name.

When i tried to deploy the second application after deploying the first. I get the error '*application type and version already exists*'.

Is there a way i can deploy both packages under a single application type name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deploy two application types with the same name to a cluster.
If you want to share services between applications, you can create two (or more) Service Fabric Application projects **with different names** and add references to the shared services to the applications (in Visual Studio, right click the References node in the application project and click Add Service).

Somewhat related to your question - you can also (using `PowerShell`):

- Create multiple instances of the same application type with different parameters after it's been deployed (`New-ServiceFabricApplication`)
- Create more instances of the same service type within an existing application (`New-ServiceFabricService`)

Comment: This is very confusing. In terns of microservices I'd like to be able to deploy them separately. And it appears that I have to chose different Application Type Names for them.